# How to Login in Android application where database is maintaining in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created an app with the database maintaining in Firebase. I have completed the user registration part and here is the coding I used,

```
if(edtUsrNameS.length() >0 && edtPassS.length() >0 &&edtEmailS.length() >0) {
                    strUsrS = edtUsrNameS.getText().toString().trim();
                    strPassS = edtPassS.getText().toString().trim();
                    strEmailS = edtEmailS.getText().toString().trim();

                    if(Constant.isValidEmail(strEmailS)){
                        edtEmailS.setError(null);

                        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
                        parameters.put(Constant.TAG_USER, strUsrS.trim());
                        parameters.put(Constant.TAG_PASS, strPassS.trim());
                        parameters.put(Constant.TAG_EMAIL, strEmailS.trim());


                        String pushId = mFirebaseInstance.getReference(Constant.FIREBASE_LOGIN).getRef().push().getKey();
                        parameters.put(Constant.TAG_KEY, pushId.trim());
                        mFirebaseInstance.getReference(Constant.FIREBASE_LOGIN).getRef().child(strUsrS.trim()).setValue(parameters);

                        Toast.makeText(Login_Reg_Activity.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                        Intent inMain = new Intent(Login_Reg_Activity.this, Login_Reg_Activity.class);
                        startActivity(inMain);

                    }else{
                        edtEmailS.setError("Enter a valid Email");
                    }

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Login_Reg_Activity.this, "Fill all detail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

After the successful registration, the data are stored in the `users` table in Firebase like this:

[image: 1]

My doubt is that how to login using the credential username and mobile. I have tried by the reference [link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-user-authentication-tutorial/), but I couldn't succeeded. So, my kind request is to direct me to do this. Also, how to restrict the duplication on user registration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: user duplication is maintain by firebase can you provide the code which you try

Comment: I haven't write code yet for duplication!!! After successful login I have to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1:**
make sure you have enabled the password login in firebase console  as shwon below in the picture
[image]

**Use Below Code For Login with email and Pwd**

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(); // same auth as you used for regestration process
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("abc@abc.com","pwd")
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        }

                    }})
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

when you get successfully login than `auth` change listner will be invoke

**Auth Change Listner**

```
 private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(user !=null){

                }
            }
        };


mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is the same reference I followed in the attached link in my question. Will try it and let you know the result...

Comment: Without email(& password) we not able to login right?

Comment: An Internal Error has occurred.

Comment: like [PASSWORD_LOGIN_DISABLED]

Comment: check the answer now i think u did not enable the login in firebase console

Comment: That error was cleared. I forgot to give Email/Password authentication in your Firebase Console under Auth > Sign-In Method.

Comment: My database design is like , details(email, password...) are saved under the username as we can seen in the image I have attached. So when I tried to login by the method you have suggest gave me a response like "EMAIL NOT FOUND"

Comment: so try to login with the email which you already register the email which i provide is dummy email

Comment: I'm getting the response like "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted." But it is there !!!

Comment: can you test with the new user like register new user and login with that user

Comment: I have saved the registration details in separate table "users". Within this 'users table' the user details are, so how to login. The above method will simply check the email & password under the project.

Comment: when you register user does it come in the user section in picture which i upload in my answer

Comment: No. I have registered in a different way, that the registered details has been saved in database in separate table and the form is what i have attached in my question.

Comment: I understood that this login will work when the same registration (using Auth) take place.

Comment: Now I'm clear on this. And I have solved the issue. Thanks for your help...

Comment: if my answer help you please accept and vote up thanks

Comment: yes definitly you will use same auth like one auth for compelte app

Comment: I am voting up your question for the multiple auth issue